# Can not convert IList to List

Tags: c#

I found this method to shuffle a list but what I would like, is for it to return the new list, and I can not seem to figure out how this is done.

Here is what I tried

```
public static class Lists {

    private static System.Random rng = new System.Random();

    public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list) {
        int n = list.Count;
        while(n > 1) {
            n--;
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
            T value = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = value;
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

What it is saying is:

> Can not convert `IList` to `List`

What I want is for the method to return the new `Shuffled` list, but I can't get it to return the list. How can this be done?

Comment: Not all `IList<T>` is `List<T>`.

Comment: Wait isn't the error `Can not convert IList to List`?

Comment: You should modify the question's title: `Can not convert IList to List`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `IList` is not necessarily a `List`. Your method returns a `List`, but is passed an `IList`:

```
public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list) {
        int n = list.Count;
        while(n > 1) {
            n--;
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
            T value = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = value;
        }
        return list; //Still an IList!
    }
```

The easiest/best solution would be to just return an `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>`.

```
public static IList<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list) {
```

If you *really* need an actual list, call `ToList`:

```
return list.ToList(); //Now its a list
```

Of course, this enumerates your collection one more time than is necessary.

Comment: I think the better solution is to return `IList<T>`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan absolutely. Was that not clear from the second paragraph?

Comment: Or not return anything at all since it's an in place shuffle.

Comment: @juharr I agree. He should return `void`. Otherwise consumers of the method could the expression that the instance passed in is unchanged.

Comment: The tricky solution like `return list.ToList();` can tempt people ;)

Comment: Doesn't return a new list as required. Also, it's within the documented requirements of `ILIst<T>` that `list[n] = value` can throw because the list is read-only.

Comment: @JonHanna Certainly the code could be improved (and does not do what the OP says it does). I was just trying to address the error (and misunderstanding about which direction he is casting)

Answer (score 1):

> Can not convert List to IList

That's because you have an `IList<T>` and you're returning a `List<T>`. You can cast `return (List<T>)list;` but this will fail if it's called with another `IList<T>`.

It will also fail before that if the `IList<T>` is readonly.

However,

> what I would like, is for it to return the new list

Well, there is no new list here. But we can easily have that be so:

```
public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> source) {
  List<T> list = new List<T>(source);
```

With this change it now creates a new list, and does the shuffle on that before it returns it.

But wait, why restrict ourselves to `IList<T>` as input? We can create a new list from any `IEnumerable<T>`, so why not do that?

```
public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
  List<T> list = new List<T>(source);
```

Still, there's a flaw in that `Random` is being used in non-single-thread code in a non-threadsafe way. That is also easily changed, remove the static `Random` and have:

```
public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
  List<T> list = new List<T>(source);
  Random rng = new System.Random();
```

Now it doesn't error, returns a new List as desired, accepts a wider range of input, and is threadsafe.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, any `List` is automatically an `IList`.  A `List` must  implement the methods defined on the `IList` interface, so it is by definition, an `IList`.

But your code is defined to receive, as input, an `IList`.  That means you can potentially pass it anything that implements the `IList` interface. So, you could pass it a `List`, or a `Dictionary`, or a ComboBoxListItems collection, or a `SortedList`, or any collection type object that implements `IList`.   Because you are "trying" to manipulate and return a `List` when you are not passed a `List` the compiler is looking to see if it can convert what you were passed into a `List`, and then complaining that it can't.  Most of the objects that implement `IList` cannot be automatically converted into a List.

Your code is confusing because the input parameter you are passing in is an `IList`, but is named ***list***.  You should fix that. and if you want to return a `List`, you need to create one in your method from whatever collection type was passed in. That's what `.ToList()` is for.

```
public static class Lists {

   private static System.Random rng = new System.Random();

   public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> iList) {
       var list = iList.ToList();
       int n = list .Count;
       while(n > 1) {
           n--;
           int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
           T value = list[k];
           list[k] = list[n];
           list[n] = value;
       }
       return list;
   }
}
```

But even better, you probably ought to type your input parameter as `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IList<T>`.  You can execute ToList() on any enumeration, so this allows your method to be utilized on a broader range of potential types.

```
public static class Lists {

   private static System.Random rng = new System.Random();

   public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> tEnumeration) {
       var list = tEnumeration.ToList();
       int n = list .Count;
       while(n > 1) {
           n--;
           int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
           T value = list[k];
           list[k] = list[n];
           list[n] = value;
       }
       return list;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Lists
{
    public static IList<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        int n = list.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
            T value = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = value;
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

- I've changed it to be `IList` as the return type instead
- I've moved the `Random` instance *inside* the method. It's all about scope and unless another method also happens to need to get random numbers then there isn't a need to have it outside the method
- Moved the opening brace onto a new line. This is not Java.

Comment: It can be better to reuse a "global" `Random` instance, but only when it can be guaranteed to be accessed from a single thread only (no thread safety!).

Comment: When is it best to have field instead of a variable?

Comment: In my opinion, when you know that no multi-threading or `async`/`await` or other parallelism occurs, it is better to stick to one single global random number generator.

Answer (score -1):

> What I want is for the method to return the new Shuffled list, but I can't get it to return the list. How can this be done?

This is not what your code does. Your code shuffles the list in place; it does not create a new one.

You can return a new List like this:

```
public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list) {
    return list.OrderBy(x => rng.Next()).ToList();
}
```

If you do want to shuffle the list in place, you should probably use the same type for the parameter and the return type. In you're case, since you're not using anything specific to `List`, you should probably use `IList`:

```
// Notice the I               
public static IList<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: True, though this doesn't really address the compilation error.

Comment: I would like to shuffle it in place, then return object I think, so then I can do something like this: `instance.Shuffle().ToArray();`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Either you copy the entire collection passed to you immediately, like in Jon Hanna's answer, or else you keep sorting the `IList<>` in place, like in your own solution, with the return type set to `void`. Modifying the original instance, and then returning a new instance with the same modified contents, is just confusing. Compare with the method `List<>.Sort` which returns `void` as well.